# How to refresh the Websphere configuration when changed from WSAdmin script?

Tags: websphere, wsadmin

I have a python script which creates bus destinations. I run the script from WSAdmin and it works fine, but the changes don't show up in the Websphere (WAS) console.

If I logout from the console and then login again, I can see the changes.

The script ends with `AdminConfig.save()`

How can I make the WAS console refresh and show the latest configuration changes? Without having to logout and login.

I run WAS version 7.0.0.15 on Windows.

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT:**

When I run another script which creates JMS queues instead, the new queues show up in the WAS console immediately. So maybe it's a bug in the WAS Console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, the WAS Integrated Solutions Console typically will show updates made from other sessions when you re-visit or refresh a page; however, there have been a few cases where this doesn't work as expected, and these usually represent bugs in the console.

I ran a quick test to create a SIB destination from `wsadmin` while I was logged into the console. I found that the change wasn't recongized when I simply re-visited the buses pages; however, when I navigated to most other pages, I was greeted with the "Your workspace has been auto-refreshed from the master configuration. You can disable auto-refresh in your user preferences." message that typically indicates when a change from another session was made. Then, after navigating back to the buses information, my new destination was visible without having to log out and log back in.

It seems that the buses pages are not detecting these changes, and this sounds like a bug. You might consider logging a PMR with IBM.

Otherwise, first, ensure that workpsace refresh is enabled (`System administration` > `Console Preferences` > `Turn on workspace automatic refresh`) - this setting is most likely already enabled by default - and then you may be able to use the workaround that I found by navigating away from the buses pages rather than logging out.

Comment: Same here. After deploying an application through a script. The refresh message pops up here after clicking a different page.

Comment: Thanks for the proposal. Tomorrow I'll check if it works for me too (before I Accept..)